# Проблема с Contains в Aiogram Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Здравствуйте написал код на aiogram :

```
eda = ['яблоко', 'груша', 'персик']

@dp.message_handler(filters.Text(contains=eda, ignore_case=True))
async def text_example(message : types.Message):
        await message.reply('Фрукты')
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что **contains** ждёт пока я все три слова напишу и только тогда реагирует, а надо чтоб он индивидуально каждое слово находил в тексте независимости от местоположения слова.
 Как это обойти?
 Рад буду помощи
Про **equals, startswith, endswith** - я знаю, они не нужны

Comment: А в чём проблема использовать `if message.text in eda: ...`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Надо чтоб когда я пишу какое то предложение и в нём есть слово "Яблоко" или" Груша" или "Персик" , бот мне отвечал- "Фрукты", через contains не получается.@Духсообщества

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так.

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: msg.text.lower() in eda)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот два решения для моего вопроса

```
eda = ['яблоко', 'банан', 'груша', 'персик']

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def main(message : types.Message):
    if any(word in message.text for word in eda):
        await message.reply('Фруты')
```

Или

```
eda = ['яблоко', 'банан', 'груша', 'персик']

@dp.message_handler(lambda msg: any(word in msg.text.lower() for word in eda))
async def text_example(message : types.Message):
        await message.reply('Фрукты')
```